# Why my password change form is getting values automatically?

Tags: php, html

I have a form on my settings page which provides users to change their password. My problem here is an input field for old password automatically gets the value of username of user logged_in and new password field gets the password. I tried changing all input types of text and it solved my problem seems browser supposes a text field followed by password field as login form. But I want to set the input type for old password to text. How do I get empty input fields?

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <label>Old Password</label> <input type="text" name="oldpassword">
   <label>New Password</label> <input type="password" name="newpassword">
   <label>Confirm Password</label> <input type="password" name="newpassword2">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to turn `autocomplete` off, but this *might* be frowned upon by many other users who use this to store their password:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <label>Old Password</label> <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="oldpassword">
  <label>New Password</label> <input autocomplete="off" type="password" name="newpassword">
  <label>Confirm Password</label> <input autocomplete="off" type="password" name="newpassword2">
</form>
```

And do you use `type="text"` for `oldpassword`? Looks like a typo for me. Please correct.

Also, in Chrome, there's a problem with `autocomplete`. You might need to use some fake fields. See [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill) for more information.

Comment: @bɪˈɡɪnə You want the old values is it?

Comment: sorry dear if I wasn't able to explain my question. it's not autocomplete problem; its showing username and password like we do with value attribute <input value="this text will be shown in input field" means no need to start typing username and password are already there. I want input fields to be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Use autocomplete and there are three ways to disable `autocomplete`

**First one in input:**

```
<input type='text' autocomplete='off' />
```

**Second one in form:**

```
<form action='' autocomplete='off'>
```

**Third one in javascript:**

```
$('input').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```